# How to update values of an existing Item in a ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listviewitem

I am working on a little project and I have to add an item with some values into a ListView.
I want to be able to update the values of an Item if it is added again and not read the same Item with different details again.

Below is the code I have managed to come up with thus far:

```
For Each item as ListViewItem in MainListView.Items
    If item.SubItems(0).Text = ItemCode Then
       item.SubItems(3).Text += ItemQty
       item.SubItems(5).Text += ItemPrice
    Else
       ' normal listview insert codes run here
    End If
Next
```

As it stands now, the values are only able to update if the Item is first on the list but once it moves a step downwards, the similar Item also inserts into the ListView with it's own records instead of finding and updating the already existing one.

Any help to rectify it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in the `else` part; anyway, try to use a `For` loop, not a `For Each` (i.e., don't change the collection while you're iterating it, if that's what you're doing now).

Comment: Jimi, the else part actually does the insertion into the ListView if the item does not already exist. In the case of a forloop , could you kindly show me how to make it identify the existing item?

Comment: What language are you actually using?  Your tags have both VBA and VB.NET - those are quite different.  Your posted code looks like .NET?

Comment: Sorry Tim, I think it was an oversight. I am using .NET

Comment: It's the same thing. Iterate from `0` to `MainListView.Items.Count - 1`. Check each item: `If MainListView.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text = ItemCode Then (...)`. I have no idea what you're adding, since you didn't post anything related to this. You should probably have a class that performs a pre-selection/filter of the data.

Comment: Hello Jim, I am getting same error and an additional one which duplicates the new entry based on the number of filled rows in the ListView

Comment: If you changed the code, than post the code you're using now. You should provide means to reproduce the error you're describing. Thus, post code that includes the objects you're trying to add to the ListView and their definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your `ListView` checking if the `ItemCode` exists. If it is found then update the item and exit the sub with the Return statement. It is OK to use the `For Each` because you are not altering the collection only changing the values of one of the items in the collection. If you were adding or removing an item from the list view you could not use the `For Each` because the collection itself is being altered.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item As ListViewItem In MainListView.Items
        If item.SubItems(0).Text = ItemCode Then
            item.SubItems(3).Text += ItemQty
            item.SubItems(5).Text += ItemPrice
            Return
        End If
    Next
    'Now if the For each fails doesn't find the record (fails to run the Return)
    ' normal listview insert codes run here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a million times Mary. It works perfectly now per your suggestions. I am most grateful. Unfortunately, I am unable to upvote but I will surely come back to do the necessary. Thanks once again.